# Prado engine trouble

Tags: engine

Tried turning engine off with key, but continued to run badly, until I needed to disconnect battery to stop engine. After a couple of hours, I went to reconnect battery, and on contact, engine kicked over. The keys were in my hand when this happened... What is happening please??

Comment: Welcome to the site. Details are important. If you **[edit]** your post to include more details about the vehicle, you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your starter relay or solenoid is energized, thereby causing the starter motor to turn. This can be caused by the stuck solenoid, relay or switch. Possibly even a short in the wiring somewhere.

With so little information given, it is hard to say for sure what is going on.